# How to repeat a method when it return a value with a delay

Tags: system.reactive

Let's say I have this observable, it calls RefreshMedias every second even if the method inside of it hasn't finished running:

```
Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
    .Subscribe(_ => PhotoSourcesService.RefreshMedias())
    .DisposeWith(Disposables);
```

How to call RefreshMedias wait the operation for completion and when it finish put a delay of 5 seconds and call RefreshMedias again indefinitely?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming `RefreshMedias()` runs synchronously and returns `void` then:

```
Observable.Defer(() => Observable.Start(() => PhotoSourcesService.RefreshMedias()))
          .Concat(Observable.Empty<Unit>().Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)))
          .Repeat()
          .DisposeWith(Disposables);
```

should work.